# For loop for outputting array in PHP cURL

Tags: php, arrays, curl, foreach

I have XML like

```
<user>
 <researcher>
  <researcher_keywords>
    <researcher_keyword>
        <value>Value A</value>
    </researcher_keyword>
    <researcher_keyword>
        <value>Value B</value>
    </researcher_keyword>
    <researcher_keyword>
        <value>Value C</value>
    </researcher_keyword>
   </researcher_keywords>
 </researcher>
</user>
```

...and I want to be able to output all the `<researcher_keyword>` values using a foreach loop or similar separated by a pipe character |

I can access specific values using code like: `$oXML->researcher->researcher_keywords->researcher_keyword[0]->value ?? null;`

...but how do I output whats in the array using a loop?

I thought something like this would work but no luck:

```
 $oXML2 = new SimpleXMLElement( $response2 );
...
 foreach($oXML2->researcher_keyword as $researcher_keyword){
    echo (string)$researcher_keyword['value'];
 }
```

and
`var_dump($oXML2->researcher->researcher_keywords);` outputs:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) { ["researcher_keyword"]=> array(7) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) { ["value"]=> string(19) "Ancient Mesopotamia" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (1) { ["value"]=> string(30) "Ancient Near Eastern religions" } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (1) { ["value"]=> string(12) "Hebrew Bible" } [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#21 (1) { ["value"]=> string(21) "American religion" } [4]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (1) { ["value"]=> string(18) "American magic" } [5]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#23 (1) { ["value"]=> string(23) "American literature" } [6]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#24 (1) { ["value"]=> string(20) "American thought" } } }
```

I could use the below code assuming there'll never be more than 10 keywords but it's not ideal.

```
  $j = 10;
  for($i = 0; $i < $j ; $i++) {
    $keyword_r = $oXML2->researcher->researcher_keywords->researcher_keyword[$i]->value ?? null;
      echo $keyword_r . "<br>";
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to loop over `$oXML2->researcher->researcher_keywords->children()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```php
$s = '<user>
 <researcher>
  <researcher_keywords>
    <researcher_keyword>
        <value>Value A</value>
    </researcher_keyword>
    <researcher_keyword>
        <value>Value B</value>
    </researcher_keyword>
    <researcher_keyword>
        <value>Value C</value>
    </researcher_keyword>
   </researcher_keywords>
 </researcher>
</user>';

$oXML2 = new SimpleXMLElement( $s );
foreach($oXML2->researcher->researcher_keywords->researcher_keyword as $word){
    echo $word->value . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks u_mulder! You rock!